# Como descobrir quem fez request em determinado arquivo PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo PHP de um sistema legado rodando perfeitamente em meu servidor que faz verificações nesse sistema e manda diversos e-mails com os alertas encontrados. No entanto, esse arquivo **é executado através de Cron Jobs, tarefas agendadas, etc.**

O problema é que **eu não faço ideia de onde está esse Cron Job** que está chamando o arquivo. Mas eu sei onde o arquivo fica e posso alterá-lo.

Existe alguma forma de descobrir, através do arquivo, quem é o cliente que está fazendo esse *request*?

Comment: Já rodou um `crontab -l` no servidor para ver a lista de tarefas agendadas?

Comment: @bfavaretto o problema está justamente aí. Não está no servidor onde está a aplicação. É algum outro servidor. Como temos muitas máquinas virtuais em nosso datacenter, não da para ficar vendo uma a uma.

Comment: Você disse que tem acesso ao script, certo? Mande o script salvar um `print_r($_SERVER)` em um log para descobrir quem o está chamando.

Comment: Fiz um pouco diferente. Adicionei no corpo do e-mail que é enviado pelo script mais uma informação: `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']; ?>`. Vamos ver agora se agora eu recebo o e-mail com o IP do servidor que fez o request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode olhar no arquivo log de acesso do apache. Geralmente no linux fica em /var/log/apache2/access.log:

```
$ grep nome_arquivo.php /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Ou colocar no seu arquivo PHP para exibir o endereço de IP da origem da requisição:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
{
 $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
{
 $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
else
{
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

echo $ip;
```

Comment: Eu havia usado somente o `REMOTE_ADDR`, mas complementei com a sua sugestão e consegui resolver o problema. No entanto, o `echo` de sair em e-mail o arquivo, já que você não verá o response no navegador. Analisar o log acredito que também resolveria, mas quando vi o tamanho do log no server, desisti pelo tamanho.